# How do I match a certificate file to a key file?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have a SSL certificate that the former sysadmin was issued (crt file.)  Searching the filesystem I found several .key files.  How do I match the crt to the key file and confirm that they match?  This is Ubuntu Server 11.10 with Apache2 modssl.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Compare the modulus of the files.

Check the public key like this:

```
openssl x509 -in /path/to/cert.crt -noout -text
```

And check the private keys like this:

```
openssl rsa -in /path/to/cert.key -noout -text
```

Compare the "modulus" data (a big block of numbers) between the certificate and the potentially matching keys.  If they match, then the key and certificate are a pair.

Comment: +1; You could also use `-modulus` instead of `-text` - which will output just the modulus (same result, but possibly easier to script with `uniq`, etc).

Comment: And use hashing to make comparisons easy on the eyeball: `openssl x509 -in /path/to/cert.crt -noout -modulus | openssl md5` and `openssl rsa -in /path/to/cert.key -noout -modulus | openssl md5`

Comment: Well, that's very handy.  Too bad I can't find a match. Guess it's time to purchase another cert.  At least I can now prove that the purchase is needed.  Cheers!

Comment: Found the match.  It was in a java keystore. I exported to PKC12 format and it was all smooth sailing from there.